# Running Scrapy from a Shell Script

Tags: bash, scrapy

I'm trying to call a number of spiders from a shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/pi/.bashrc
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

workon email-scraper
cdvirtualenv

#Change to dir containing scrapy.cfg
cd ./sitecode/jobscraper
pwd

scrapy crawl site1
scrapy crawl site2
scrapy crawl site3

# Email me the jobs.csv file
python '/home/pi/Documents/jobscraper/scripts/jobs-mail.py'

# Delete the file so a new one is created on next scrape
# sudo rm /home/pi/Documents/jobscraper/csv/jobs.csv
```

The only part it executes properly is the python script at the end, which emails me an empty csv file as none of the scrapers have run. I get the following output when running the above script from BASH

```
(email-scraper)pi@raspberrypi ~/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/sitecode $ sudo sh runspiders.sh 
ERROR: Environment 'email-scraper' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv email-scraper'.
ERROR: no virtualenv active, or active virtualenv is missing
runspiders.sh: line 9: cd: ./sitecode/jobscraper: No such file or directory
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/sitecode
runspiders.sh: line 13: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 14: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 15: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 16: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 17: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 18: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 19: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 20: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 21: scrapy: command not found
runspiders.sh: line 22: scrapy: command not found
```

I'm very new to shell scripting. Can anyone illustrate how to make sure I activate the virtualenv and change into the correct dir before calling the first spider?

**Edit** In reply to @konsolebox

This is how I would run the scraper manually from the home dir:

First, source .bashrc as the raspberry pi doesn't do this automatically for some reason.

```
source .bashrc
```

This allows me access to virtualenvwrapper. I can then

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ workon email-scraper
(email-scraper)pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cdvirtualenv
```

which puts me in the virtualenv project directory `/home/pi/.virtualenvs/email-scraper`

I then do

```
cd sitecode/jobscraper
```

and ls -al puts me in the dir with access to scrapy.cfg, which I need in order to run the scraper.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi    4096 Sep  9 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi   pi    4096 Sep  8 19:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi   pi    4096 Sep  8 14:59 jobscraper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi     632 Sep  8 22:18 runspiders.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Sep  9 19:40 .runspiders.sh.swp
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi     381 Sep  7 23:34 scrapy.cfg
```

I can then do `scrapy crawl site1` to run the scraper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you actually need to run the script in `~/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/`. Do `cd ~/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/` before running it.

When you're there run

`sh sitecode/runspiders.sh`

Or

`sudo sh sitecode/runspiders.sh`

---

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi
source ./bashrc
## source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh  ## You didn't run this.

workon email-scraper
cdvirtualenv

cd ./sitecode/jobscraper

scrapy crawl site1
```

Run as `bash script.sh`, not `sudo sh script.sh`.

Comment: I moved runspiders.sh to `/home/pi/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/sitecode/jobscraper` and it now runs the spiders (or at least is running the first one) but bash is telling me that `source` and `workon` and `cdvirtualenv` commands are not found.

Comment: @puffin Why did you have to move it there? Also I think you need to call it through `bash` not `sh`. So run it as `bash sitecode/runspiders.sh` when you're in `~/.virtualenvs/email-scraper/`.

Comment: when I do `(email-scraper)pi@raspberrypi ~/.virtualenvs/email-scraper $ sudo bash ./sitecode/runspiders.sh` I still get the `command not found`... Moving the runspiders.sh to the same directory as scrapy.cfg seems to work. I thought it might work because the script is running as the same dir as .cfg and will have access to it. I'm still not any further forward in my understanding.

Comment: @puffin Can you make an update for us showing how you could run scrapy manually? (not through the script). I actually would have installed it here as well just to try it but it has many dependencies. Also, I think you actually have to start running the script on your home directory not on `~/.virtualenv`, but that's just a guess. I don't really have much clue. Please show us how it could be done manually starting from `~/`.

Comment: @puffin I compiled your commands (see update). Place it in your home directory (`/home/pi`) then execute the script as bash (`bash script.sh`). It seems like you didn't have to run it with `sudo`? If you run the script as `sudo` you would be doing it as a different user and so the home directory and virtualenvs would be different from it. And it seems you didn't have virtualenvs as root. I made the script simple this time just to know how it works.

Comment: I have changed the script as you suggested and ran it in `/home/pi` and it works. Why must it be run from the home directory, especially if i am specifying absolute paths to the files I want executed?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really necessary to run it in home but perhaps it's necessary for `workon` or `cdvirtualenv`.

Comment: I think it's because when run in the home directory, the script will have access to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, but while in an activated virtualenv, `/usr/local/bin` points to the `bin` folder in the virtualenv, which doesn't contain virtualenvwrapper.sh?